# How to import OpenSSL in Python to fetch the serial number of the certificate

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, pyopenssl

I have a certificate and i used the regular expression to strip the beginning and ending from certificate. How can i decode the **serial number** of the certificate using OpenSSL.

I have the cli command to decode:

```
openssl x509 -serial -noout
```

how can fetch it from **Python**

Comment: What have you tried or researched already?

Comment: @KlausD. i tried ' openssl x509 -in CERTIFICATE_FILE -serial -noout'  where variable CERTIFICATE_FILE is having the certificate ( after stripped using regex). Failed.

Comment: Show us your Python code!

Comment: `m = re.search(r"(?<=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----).*?(?=-----END CERTIFICATE-----)", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print( m.group() )

CERTIFICATE_FILE= m.group()

res= subprocess.getstatusoutput('openssl x509 -in CERTIFICATE_FILE -serial -noout'  )

print(res)`  @KlausD.